# Is there a way to run Restful API call every 12 hours in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest

I have this project in mind , I want to be able to run  API call every 12 hours and store in the database , the database data will be deleted and new data will be inserted,
How can i accomplish this in PHP Laravel ?

Comment: use cron to schedule the task

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a command to run weekly on Monday using Laravel's command scheduler:

```
// Run once per week on Monday at 1 PM...
$schedule->call(function () {
    //
})->weekly()->mondays()->at('13:00');

// Run hourly from 8 AM to 5 PM on weekdays...
$schedule->command('foo')
          ->weekdays()
          ->hourly()
          ->timezone('America/Chicago')
          ->between('8:00', '17:00');
```

If you host your project on the Linux based operating system , you can set Cron jobs for doing task every 12 hours manually.
Also you can do it with Scheduler in windows.